# Where can I find left-handed serrated knives?

Tags: equipment, knives

I recently discovered that the reason I hate cheese knives (but love cheese) is because they are made to work for right-handed people.

So where can I buy a (reasonably priced) cheese knife, or other serrated knives?

Comment: What, so we are allowing left handed people to use the site now?  What next?

Answer (score 5):

We have been selling left handed products now for 50 years this year - supplying the vast majority of specialist left handed stores around the world.

I can confirm that Left handers do indeed need knives that are sharpened / scalloped / serrated on the opposite side to a right handed blade. So, holding the knife in your left hand - pointing it away from your body - the scallop / serration / etc should be on the right (nearest your body). This will dramatically improve the way that you cut meat / veg / etc - and be safer for you as well.

You should be able to find Paring / Vegetable / Cook's / Bread / Cheese knives - and many more at any good left handed specialist store.

Answer (score 1):

All professional knives (except for single-bladed Japanese sashimi knives) are ambidextrous.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this? I just checked my girlfriend's bread knife from culinary school and it is not the same on both sides. Edit: and even if they were, doesn't answer my question about where to find left-handed cheese knife since they probably don't fall into the 'professional knife' category.

Comment: Are you quite sure? Sounds like a crap knife to me. I should have said 'almost all' I suppose. There is no benefit in a serrated knife being handed; for sashimi knives, it allows the knife to be much sharper (like a razor blade). As for your cheese knives, http://www.anythingleft-handed.co.uk